# Shops refresh when?

Tags: dead-island

Traders each offer an inventory of items that changes every so often. What is the period at which the offering updates?

Comment: In my copy there was a countdown on the vendor..

Comment: @Timelord64 http://puu.sh/kQNGt/6f5821d612.png I just took this screenshot. This is the latest version (1.3.0). Where is the countdown?